# Node js continuously share data with python script on backround

Tags: python, node.js, child-process

I have node js and I want to send and get back data from python script running on background. (I know about child process and python-shell lib, but I need to run python script on background in reason of hideous start time.)

I have something like this:

```
//Python script
While True:
  text = input()
  response = get_response(text)
```

I need to get input from js script and return back reponse. I know, I sould rewrite this as function, but I don't know how to manage the communication with js script without starting python script each call. Python script sould be running on backround and just recieve and return input and response. Any tips how handle it in js?

Comment: It sounds like you want some sort of connection between the two processes so each process can send data to the other.  There are dozens of ways to do that (stdin/stdout, webSocket connection between the two processes, one process is an http server, the other makes http requests, etc...).

Comment: The easiest, quickest to deploy solution is probably to make your Python method a [Flask](https://www.fullstackpython.com/flask.html) route.

Comment: Can I use stdin/stdout from python-shell to connection with function in running script?